# What is this "loop (..) { .. }" syntax construct? (Not in K&R)

Tags: c, loops, syntax

C isn't my first language, but I've written a good bit of it.  I am examining a code and I have come across a construct I have never see before:

```
loop(i,nlevels)
{
  /* do stuff based on "i"  */
}
```

There is no `do`, `for`, or `while`.  "i" is not acted on inside the loop.  I assume this means loop over "i" sequentially from 0 to nlevels (or maybe nlevels-1), but I don't know.  I can't find this in K&R.  I can't find it on the internet.  Can someone enlighten me?  Thanks.

Comment: There is a macro. First step is to find it :D

Comment: Check for preprocessor macros.

Comment: Look for a macro, find out who did it, and slap him for me. :)

Comment: Gah, how awful. If this isn't too localized I don't know what is. Vote to close.

Comment: I disagree that this is localized.  I have come across macros like this several times. This question will likely help other searchers.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`loop` is most certainly a macro someone defined as it's not part of the C language.

Search for a `#define loop`.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  Thanks very much to everyone who responded.  I'm accepting Pubby's answer since he apparently got here first, but thanks to all of you.

Comment: @bob.sacamento For the record, the macro means that whoever wrote the code was a very bad C programmer. That might be useful to consider if you have to read more code by the same person.

Answer (score 14):

This macro is probably defined somewhere:

```
#define loop(index, steps) for(int index = 0; index <= steps; index++)
```

Or one that is looking very similar to it

Answer (score 4):

Is loop a macro #defined somewhere?  It seems an easy enough macro that someone may want to have done so.